# remove public from url laravel on localhost

Tags: laravel, localhost

Every single project I have to look up why i can't access the website and have to come up with solutions like this:

> I am working on laravel 5.4 project and want to remove public from
>   url.Right now my url is localhost/project_name/public/login. Please
>   suggest me way remove public from url.

but on localhost this problem isnt available, often routing is different to, i upload my project and gone are all images, have to change the path etc.

Is it possible to configure localhost more to reality, so you can tackle these problems while you are coding, and not have to panic once you upload your project?

Comment: yea, use virtual hosts for each 'project' ... also don't reference assets by relative paths

Comment: There are a variety of ways of configuring dev to be more like production. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/valet might be the easiest way to start.

Comment: It is not clear what do you use for localhost: apache, nginx or php itself (via artisan serve).